# Django exception handling cancels non-atomic transaction mode

Tags: python, django, exception

Best described by example.
Consider the following code (*Django 1.9*)

View:

```
@transaction.non_atomic_requests
def error_generating_view(request):
    modelA = ModelA(...)
    modelA.save()
    if (some_bad_condition)
       return json_error_msg ('Some custom message')
    return HttpResponse(True)
```

View in other module

```
def json_error_msg(error_message):
    return JsonResponse(json.dumps(error_message, ensure_ascii=False), status = 500, safe = False)
```

Django seems to through an exception to client-side, but the problem here is that modelA instance is saved, although I set up `@transaction.non_atomic_requests`. It looks like I am doing something wrong with exception handling syntax.

Could anyone point to what exactly I should rectify here to make Django through customized exception message to client and simultaneously treat the entire view as terminated incorrectly so that the transaction is rolled back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic%20%60transation.atomic%60) decorator, not `transaction.non_atomic_requests` - by using `transaction.non_atomic_requests` you're telling Django, that this request should NOT be wrapped in transaction (every change is auto-commited to the database)