# Exception handling and atomic requests in Django

Tags: django, exception, transactions

I've previously [a similar questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790388/django-exception-handling-cancels-non-atomic-transaction-mode/40790826#40790826)n, but I put it incorrectly, that's why need to clarify it in a new post.

Consider the following Django settings and a view:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # ...
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    },
```

view:

```
def my_view(request):
    foo = Foo.objects.get(id = 1)
    foo.some_field = 'new value'
    foo.save()
    if some_condition(): 
       # ...
    else:
      return JsonResponse(json.dumps('Cusom message', ensure_ascii=False), 
                          status = 500, 
                          safe = False)
```

The problem with this code is that `foo` object is updated if `some_condition` is not true, whereas I would expect the transaction to roll back, since I am sending status 500. Could anyone give me a hint on what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Sending a 500 doesn't cause transactions to roll back.

Comment: Don't use atomic requests; wrap the relevant code explicitly with the [`atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) context manager and send whatever response you need.

Comment: Daniel, could you please provide a code a snippet, so that I am sure I implement your recommendation is most appropriate way

Comment: And will sending 500 roll back the transaction, or I should do something else to roll it back ?

Comment: A response with a `500` status code is not an exception -- only an exception will roll back the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @Daniel’s comment, here is how you can do it with a custom atomic block:

```
from django.db import transaction


def my_view(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            foo = Foo.objects.get(id = 1)
            foo.some_field = 'new value'
            foo.save()
            if not some_condition():
                raise Exception('This exception is to force rollback')
            # ...
    except Exception:
      return JsonResponse(json.dumps('Cusom message', ensure_ascii=False), 
                          status = 500, 
                          safe = False)
```

So the trick here is if the `with transaction.atomic()` block exits due to an exception, the any statements executed within that transaction block get rolled back.  We catch the exception outside the with block so that we can send the 500 response back to the caller.